# Is there anyway to get the class name that an instance is injected into (using ninject)?

Tags: ninject

I'm injecting my dependencies into my classes fine, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get the class name I'm injecting into?

For example:

```
Bind<ISomething>.ToMethod(c => new Something([GIVE INJECTING *TO* CLASS NAME]));
```

So, if I had:

```
public class Blah{
  public Blah(ISomething something) { /**/ }
}
```

When injecting Ninject would in effect call:

```
new Blah(new Something("Blah"));
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. You use the `IContext` you're given in the `ToMethod` method to get the name of the type you're being injected into like this:

```
Bind<ISomething>().ToMethod(c => new Something(GetParentTypeName(c)));
```

Which uses this little helper method (which could also be turned into a nice extension method):

```
private string GetParentTypeName(IContext context)
{
    return context.Request.ParentRequest.ParentRequest.Target.Member.DeclaringType.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has probably changed in later versions of Ninject. As for version v3.2.0 the accepted solution didn't work for me.

The following does though:

```
Bind<ISomething>().ToMethod((ctx) 
       => new Something(ctx.Request.Target?.Member?.DeclaringType?.Name ?? ""));
```